# CMDeviceMotion heading is -1.0

Tags: ios, ios11, core-motion

There is a new [heading property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion/2890756-heading) of CMDeviceMotion in iOS 11.

I'm trying to use it but find that it's always `-1.0`. It's supposed to hold degrees as a Double from `0.0` to `360.0`.

My app targets iOS 11+, and I'm testing on a physical device (iPhone) running iOS 11.

```
let mmgr = CMMotionManager()
mmgr.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true // for calibrating magnetometer, maybe not needed?
mmgr.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
mmgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main, withHandler: { (motionData: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
    if let motion = motionData {
        print("heading:", motion.heading) // always -1.0
    }
})
```

I can get other properties just fine, such as `motion.attitude.roll`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that I needed to start motion updates with a different method signature which includes the `CMAttitudeReferenceFrame` option:

```
let mmgr = CMMotionManager()
mmgr.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
mmgr.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical, to: .main, withHandler: { (motionData: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
    if let motion = motionData {
        print("heading:", motion.heading) // works
    }
})
```

The [What's New in iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS_11_0.html) guide states that if you use `xArbitraryZVertical` (default) or `xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical` for the CMAttitudeReferenceFrame option, the heading will always be -1.

This helpful tidbit is not stated in the `heading` property reference.

Comment: It is not actually necessary to call `startDeviceMotionUpdates(using:to:withHandler:)` so your answer should not specify that. What's necessary is merely that the motion manager should have a reference frame that contains the term `North`. There are other ways to ensure that.